# How to overload comparison operator with matrix class?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

No matter how hard I search I can not figure this out. I have to do a project with overloading operators and the only two I am having trouble with are == and !=. For the project directions == is defined as the rows, columns, and values of both matrices being identical.

so far for the == all I have is this:

```
bool Matrix::operator==(const Matrix & m) {
// not sure what to return if all values must be equal
}
```

Question is: what do I return and compare in the function for this to work properly?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematical terms, matrix equality requires all corresponding elements of two matrices, **A** and **B** have the same value.  Thus
**A** = **B** if and only if **A**<sub>*i*,*j*</sub> = **B**<sub>*i*,*j*</sub> for all *i*, *j*.

In your case, where you are looking at implementation in C++, you will need to verify the `Matrix` instances `this` and `m` are the same size, and they each contain the same value at corresponding locations. If they are the same size and have the same values in the corresponding locations, then `==` will return `true` (`false` otherwise), and `!=` will return `false` (`true` otherwise).

Comment: so if everything checks out, for == i can do: return true; and if it doesn't work return false; ?

Comment: alright thanks a lot man. say I have a matrix object a and matrix object b that are equal to each other. To test that this works would I just be able to cout << a == b << endl; and get true to be out put?

Comment: @tmricks94 You might get `1` instead of `true`, but yes, it should work out that way.  Also, you might need to surround the `a==b` with parentheses to make sure the compiler is clear on your meaning.